# Erro 404 - Not Found

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, laravel-5.3, virtualhost

Boa tarde,

Estou a fazer um projecto onde tenho instalado o php7, mysql, apache2 numa virtualbox com o ubuntu16.04.
Estou a trabalhar localmente e instalei o laravel, 5.3.
Tenho uma api já feita que estava a funcionar mas fiz um Virtual host, em que criei um novo virtual Host e coloquei o `DocumentRoot minha_pasta` e o `ServerName nome_virtual_host`. Depois fui ao ficheiro dos hosts e coloquei uma nova linha com 127.0.0.1 nome_virtual_host. 
Quando no browser coloco `http://nome_virtual_host`, aparece-me a página do laravel como era suposto mas quando faço `http://nome_virtual_host/api`, antes dava-me código JSOn como era suposto e agora aparece-me:

```
Not Found

    The requested URL /api was not found on this server.

    Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at nome_virtual_host Port 80
```

Como posso resolver o problema?

Comment: É Laravel 5.3? Catarina

Comment: _Sim é._ @Miguel

Comment: Opps desculpa, não li essa parte, distração

Comment: Mexeste em .htaccess? Pôes a app a correr com `php artisan serv`? E se fores a `http://nome_virtual_host/public/api`, o que dá?

Comment: _não mexi no .htaccess, o que tenho que fazer nesse ficheiro? e se colocar o php artisan serve a correr consigo com: (http://nome_virtual_host:8000/api), quando alterei o virtual host no DocumentRoot já coloquei a pasta public também. Só que tenho que colocar é a porta 8000_@Miguel